# How to use KNN in Matlab

Tags: matlab, knn

I need to use KNN in matlab to find the closest data in training data from **`A`**.

I have data in .mat that has this kind of information (training data):

```
train_data =   1 232 34 21 0.542 

               2 32 333 542 0.32
```

and so on.

Then i have a second information that I will gather through the application but I will only get

```
A = 2 343 543 43 0.23
```

So now my question is do i only need to do is something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/classificationknnclass.html), and can i use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855461/knn-algo-in-matlab)?

Does KNN need to learn something or do you only need to load test data and some present data (like **`A`**) and go through some formula or preload in another function that learns it then through a second function to give you the result.

Best regards.

Comment: What do the 5 numbers represent? Are they coordinates in 5D space, or how should I see them?

Comment: The first number is object code (like apple is 1, orange is 2). The second three numbers are RGB, and the last one is roundness of an object. Now the A is data gathered in real time, train_data is gathered via a GUI and it contains data about the fruit.

Answer (score 3):

So you have a training set (with labels) and some test data without labels? I think you can use the function you linked to `classificationknn()`. If i understand your question you want something like the example: **Predict Classification Based on a KNN Classifier**

http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/classification-using-nearest-neighbors.html#btap7nm